# Help with this PDE problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given the equation $au_{xx}(x,t)-bu_{t}(x,t)+cu(x,t)=0$

define $w(x,t)=e^{\delta t}u(x,t)$ and find the equation satisfied by $w$.

Could you guys give me a hint on how to proceed, or a reference that can help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: $$w(x,t) = e^{\delta t} u(x,t) \implies u(x,t) = e^{-\delta t} w(x,t)$$ Now compute $u_{t}$ and $u_{xx}$ and substitute into your PDE to get an equation in $w$.

Comment: thanks for the hint, can you recommend a good book for this topic?

Comment: You mean a good book for an introduction to PDEs? Maybe Kreyszigs 'Applied Engineering Mathematics'. Your question above is just a straight forward application of the product rule though..

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorta curious to see how this works out, so:

With

$au_{xx}(x, t) - bu_t(x, t) + cu(x, t) = 0, \tag 1$

and

$w(x, t) = e^{\delta t}u(x, t), \tag 2$

we have, per the suggestion in the comment of Mattos,

$u(x, t) = e^{-\delta t} w(x, t), \tag 3$

from which

$u_{xx} = e^{-\delta t} w_{xx}(x, t), \tag 4$

$u_t(x, t) = -\delta e^{-\delta t} w(x, t) + e^{-\delta t} w_t(x, t); \tag 5$

we assemble (3)-(5) into (1):

$a e^{-\delta t} w_{xx}(x, t) - b(-\delta e^{-\delta t} w(x, t) + e^{-\delta t} w_t(x, t)) + c e^{-\delta t} w(x, t)$
$= e^{-\delta t}(a  w_{xx}(x, t) + b\delta  w(x, t) -  bw_t(x, t) + c  w(x, t))$
$= e^{-\delta t}(aw_{xx}(x, t) - bw_t(x, t) + (c + \delta b)w(x, t)); \tag 6$

it now follows by virtue of (1) that

$e^{-\delta t}(aw_{xx}(x, t) - bw_t(x, t) + (c + \delta b)w(x, t)) = 0, \tag 7$

whence, upon multiplication by $e^{\delta t}$,

$aw_{xx}(x, t) - bw_t(x, t) + (c + \delta b)w(x, t) = 0. \tag 8$

Comment: @Chinny84:  that's probably a goal of the exercise, and his identity is but the first step.

Comment: That is a fair point.

Comment: For those that want to know: usually, at the point Robert reached at the end (equation $8$), you would take $\delta = -c/b$ in order to transform the original PDE into the heat equation in $w$. Then, we would solve the problem in $w$ and transform back to get the solution $u$.

Comment: Actually this exercise had parts a) and b), part a) was the one posted, and part b) was to suppose that b is not zero and choose a $\delta$  that did just that...